# .htaccess redirects according to the query string contents

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, referrer, http-referer

I have an online archive of images, some of which reside on Cloud Storage. The archive is hierarchical with four levels, and the appropriate level is accessed using query strings:

```
a.php?level=image&collection=a&document=b&item=72
```

The level can be archive, collection, document, or image.

I want to prevent robots from accessing the actual images, primarily to minimise traffic on the cloud storage. So the idea is if they issue a request where the query string level parameter is image ("?level=image"), that request is diverted.

The `.htaccess` code below is intended to check the query string for a request from a foreign referrer, and if the request is for an image, direct the request elsewhere:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^level=image$
  RewriteRule (.*) https://a.co.uk/blank.htm [NC,R,L]
```

My code appears to have no obvious effect. Can anybody see what I am doing wrong? I do not pretend to have a lot of confidence with `.htaccess` code, normally relying on snippets produced by people cleverer than me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^level=image$
> ```

This checks that the query string is exactly equal to `level=image`, whereas in your example the `level` URL parameter is just one of many (the first one).

To check that the URL parameter `level=image` appears anywhere in the query string then modify the above *condition* like so:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)level=image($|&)
```

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1
> ```

Minor issue, but this would allow referrers where the requested hostname (eg. `example.com`) occurs only as a subdomain of the referrer. eg. `example.com.referrer.com`. To resolve this, modify the *CondPattern* to include a trailing slash or end-of-string anchor. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1(/|$)
```

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*) https://a.co.uk/blank.htm [NC,R,L]
> ```

There's no need for the capturing subpattern. If you only need the rule to be successful for any URL-path then use just `^` to avoid traversing the URL-path. But in your example, the request is for `a.php`, not "any URL"?

But why "redirect", rather than simply block the request? As you say, this is for "robots" after all. For example, to send a 403 Forbidden:

```
RewriteRule ^a\.php$ - [F]
```

---

#### In summary:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1(/|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)level=image($|&)
RewriteRule ^a\.php$ - [F]
```

Note, however, that search engine "bots" generally don't send a `Referer` header at all. And it is trivial for arbitrary bots to fake the `Referer` header and circumvent your block.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive reply. Unfortunately, it still fails to work. I am unsure about the meaning of the bracketed sections in the regular expression, in particular the "or &" bit.

My test program, run from a different server is:

$url = "https://archives.bcra.org.uk/archive.php?level=image&collection=wilkinson&document=miscellaneous&item=8";
echo"<h2>$url</h2>\n";
$page = file_get_contents($url);
echo $page;

Comment: @Braemoor Do you have any other directives in the `.htaccess` file? Is the `.htaccess` file being processed? What is the value of the `Referer` header in your test request?

Comment: Cracked it! I changed "RewriteRule ^a.php$ - [F]" to "RewriteRule .php$ - [F]", and it works a treat. Thank you.

Comment: @Braemoor You're welcome. I only used `a.php`, because that was the example URL you gave in the question. (?)